# How to include the "--include" curl tag when posting?

Tags: powershell

Pretty straightforward question. Posting with:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://www.myWebsite.com/extension -Method POST -Body $myLocalFile
```

How can I add the "--include" cURL tag to this POST request so I get more information back from the server?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [cURL documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), `--include` does the following:

> (HTTP) Include the HTTP-header in the output. The HTTP-header includes things like server-name, date of the document, HTTP-version and more...

`Invoke-WebRequest` returns a `HtmlWebResponseObject` object, and one of the properties of the object is called `Headers`. That object is a hashtable containing the HTTP headers that came along with the HTTP response, and you can select that collection & look at the contents easily.

```
$Headers = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://www.myWebsite.com/extension -Method POST -Body $myLocalFile |
    Select-object -expandproperty Headers
```

Or, if you need to capture the whole response & pick through it:

```
$Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://www.myWebsite.com/extension -Method POST -Body $myLocalFile;
$Response.headers;
```

Comment: I tried the first of your two suggestions and now instead of the basic server response being printed, nothing is printed at all?

Comment: In the first example, the HTTP headers will be captured into the variable `$Headers` and nothing is output to the host (and the rest of the response is lost to the ether). In the second, the whole HTTP response will be captured into `$Response` and you can get the content from `$Response.Content`.